# Why do I get a PHP 5.2.6 segmentation fault when using PDO_SQlite?

Tags: php, debian, php5, sqlite, pdo

This is an installation on ModWest's shared hosting.  I have enabled both PDO and PDO_sqlite on the server and phpinfo() verifies both are running.  When I access PDO itself, I'm fine, and getting a meaningful error.

```
<?php
  $dbh = new PDO("");
?>
```

This gives me an "Invalid Connection String" error.

But, as soon as I begin a connection string with **`sqlite:`**, I get a total crash.  When I run via the webserver, I'm seeing NO error.  When I enter a nonexistant filename, PHP does indeed create the file.

I tried running the constructor via CLI and there I do get a simple error:

**Segmentation Fault**

I'm not seeing ANYTHING in the PHP 5.2.6 changelogs about this bug.  Anyone have any additional troubleshooting steps?

The OS is Debian 5.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it came from enabling PDO and pdo_sqlite but NOT sqlite itself.

Answer (score 0):

Is the server running Zend?  Zend 3.3.9?  Ioncube?

One or the other of those is probably not the latest version which causes a segfault due to an invalid jump address.

Comment: You mean Zend Optimizer?  Yes, it is.  The version is not shown.

Comment: check the /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini file (or the equivalent for your distribution) and it should show the current version in the line that says  zend_optimizer.version=  Or, create a page with phpinfo() and look for the line that says with Zend Optimizer v3.3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2007, by Zend Technologies